# why does grep produce this behavior with these files

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have two files in this format, although they have the same amount of columns, the actual files have significantly more rows.

file1

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

file2

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Both files have the same amount of columns and rows, and are formatted exactly the same, to my knowledge. None of the files have an extension, so no `.csv` or `.txt` it's simply the file name. I wanted to compare each row in the files and output the count of the matching rows. So look at row 1 in file1 and then row 1 in file2 and if the match that gets a one and so forth.

To do this I've done `grep -c -f file1 file2` in the past however, this time when I try to do it, grep never stops running, and it takes up an entire core. Now when I do `grep -w -c -f file1 file2` I do get back a count of the matching lines in the files, however what is strange is if I change the order so if I do `grep -w -c -f file2 file1` I get back a different number.

The actual files each have 2983 rows and 61 columns. For those files if I do `grep -w -c -f file1 file2` I get back 2021 but if I do `grep -w -c -f file2 file1` I get back 1950

Also if I do `diff file1 file2` I get this output at the end of the other output `\ No newline at end of file` but if I do `diff -w file1 file2` the no newline message is no longer returned.

Comment: have you tried `dos2unix` your files?

Comment: I haven't, but I will look into it now

Comment: any blank lines at the end? if there's a blank line in the -f input file, it'll count as a null pattern and match everything.

Comment: @EugeniuRosca after `dos2unix` I no longer need `-w` in the grep command, `grep -c -f` now runs and terminates. @Marc B there was one empty line at the end in each file, I have removed them, however I still get the behavior of the order changing the count results. `grep -c -f file1 file2` gives a different result than `grep -c -f file2 file1`

Comment: Differing counts would mean that you have duplicate lines in one of the files. When you search from the file with the duplicates you find fewer matches because the searched file only has the line once. When you search from the file *without* the duplicates the duplicated line is matched more than once. See [this](http://ideone.com/5fN848) for example.

Comment: this is brilliant thank you! it seems then grep would not be what I want since it doesn't take the line number into account....actually what if I add in a key in the first column which is simply the line number in both files, that should get rid of duplicates right?

Comment: @anubhava I have figured it out, and tested it, it worked the way I want it to. by adding a column with numbers that correspond to the line number, this forces the order to be taken into account and it gets rid of duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find the common lines, use `comm` or `grep -Fx`

```
comm -12 file1 file2

grep -Fx -f file1 file2
```

---

You comment: "it worked the way I want it to. by adding a column with numbers that correspond to the line number"

So, you only want to match if line number N in file1 is the same as line number N in file2:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {line[FNR] = $0; next} $0 == line[FNR]' file1 file2
```

or with bash (this will likely be slower, but consume less memory):

```
while IFS= read -u3 -r line1; IFS= read -u4 -r line2; do
    [ "$line1" = "$line2" ] && echo "$line1"
done 3<file1 4<file2
```

Comment: this results in the same thing as before. depending on the order I either get 1950 lines or 2021 lines returned. `grep -Fx -f file1 file2` = 2021 lines returned while `grep -Fx -f file2 file1` = 1950 lines returned

as for the `comm -12` command I get a return of 3 lines then `comm: file1 is not in sorted order` and same thing `comm: file2 is not in sorted order` and then 36 more common lines.

Comment: The different line counts are not unusual. Suppose that file1 contains the line "foo" 3 times and file2 contains the line "foo" 5 times. Then "grep -Fx -f file1 file2" will return the 5 "foo" lines in file2, while "grep -Fx -f file2 file1" will return the 3 "foo" lines in file1.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent tool called diff designed for exactly this purpose:

```
diff -c file1 file2 #Difference
comm -1 -2 file1 file2 #Common
```

This will tell you matching lines, and also exactly specify where lines differ.